# Getting JAXB IllegalAnnotationExceptions preparing to UnMarshal

Tags: java, jaxb

I tried looking up on solutions here but none of them worked for me. Hence the post.

Here is the code that I am using to call the JAXBContext

```
final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { ClassA.class, ClassB.class });
final Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
return (ClassA) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(content);
```

Here is my sample XML which I am trying to unMarshall:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ElementList>
    <Element El1="111" EL2="222" EL3="333" EL4="444" />
    <Element El1="1111" EL2="22222" EL3="3333" EL4="4444" />
</ElementList
```

ClassA:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ElementList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class ClassA {

    @XmlElement(name = "Element")
    private List<ClassB> classBList;

    ClassA(final List<ClassB> classBList) {
        this.classBList = classBList;
    }

    List<ClassB> getClassBList() {
        return classBList;
    }

    void setClassBList(final List<ClassB> classBList) 
   {
        this.classBList = classBList;
   }
}
```

ClassB:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Element")
@XmlType(name = "Element", propOrder = { "El1Value", "EL2Value", "EL3Value", "EL4Value"})
class ClassB {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "El1")
    private String El1Value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "EL2")
    private String EL2Value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "EL3")
    private String EL3Value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "EL4")
    private String EL4Value;

    //Getters and Setters for values
}
```

I am getting

```
1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
```

Even after going over other solutions I am getting this, so I am sure that I missed something or am doing something not right. I have spend good part of a day on this.

Could someone help me figure this out? I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your code and this is the full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.package.ClassA does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.package.ClassA
```

Unmarshalling fails because class A is missing a default constructor, that is, a constructor without arguments. Adding one does the trick.

Comment: That fixed the issue. I did not anticipate need to create an empty default constructor, which is weird, but It works. Thank you!!